# Android : AlertDialog shown twice instead of once

Tags: android, alert

I have an android app in which when the users touch or click the `EditText`, the content of the `EditText` is shown in the `AlertDialog`. I added a done `Button` to it, but the `AlertDialog` does not dismiss. I have to press the done button twice. I am not able to know why this is happening and can any anyone suggest a better alternative other than toast?

Coding Part:
    I am calling the following  function on touch.

```
public void setalert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            mContext);

    // set title


    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
    .setMessage(etDesc.getText().toString())
    .setCancelable(false)


    .setNegativeButton("Done",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            // if this button is clicked, just close
            // the dialog box and do nothing

            dialog.cancel();                                                            

        }
    });                 

    // show it
    alertDialogBuilder.show();

}
```

Comment: check this change your onTouch like that..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983764/bug-or-error-in-dialogpicker/22983886#22983886]

Comment: change Listencer- use onClickLictener

Comment: ok.. will try this with on click

Comment: Did it with on click listener works fine now. thanks

Comment: when you try to touch button or any control ontouchlistner call 2-3 times,that`s your dialog open 2 times.try to put log value in 
ontouchlistner you will get idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This under your OnCreate**

```
ettext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        setalert2();
                    }

                });
```

**This under your program**

```
 public void setalert2()
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    mContext);

                // set title


                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage(ettext.getText().toString())
                    .setCancelable(true);







                    // show it
                alertDialogBuilder.show();

                }
```

Answer (score 4):

Its because touch event is called twice:

1.`MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

when user finger down on edittext.

2.`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

when user finger up from edittext.

to avoid this do it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       setalert();
    }
}
```